# firebase_auth/too-many-requests Firebase Phone Auth flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

i'm testing my android app and trying to send verification codes on my number and give following exception: firebase_auth/too-many-requests. I know about debug phone numbers, but sometimes i want to test my real number. Before this exception no more than 5 tryes. Is it possible to change number of tryes before this exception?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't change this limit.